# textview and progress bar will update from a wifi connection but not from bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, user-interface, bluetooth, progress-bar

I am experiencing very strange behavior and as I am fairly new to Android I am not sure if I am missing a concept so I am hoping for some help on this.

I have an application that can receive data using either a bluetooth connection or using a wifi connection. Both of these connections receive identical data, it is simply a matter of how the user chooses to go about it. The issue I experience is originally when I log into my application my progress bars and text views update as needed from wifi. Then if I establish a bluetooth connection, the UI updates as expected as well. However, as soon as I switch activities and then come back to the activity with the progress bars and text views, anything coming from bluetooth will not update the UI's. However, if I refresh my information through wifi, the UI does update as expected and as it did before.

I have debugged and I know for a fact that all my data is coming in as it should and is being checked accordingly. I also know that bluetooth is definitely connected. I have researched this issue, and I have seen people use separate threads to manage UI's. I have tried this as well and the behavior didn't change.

Perhaps there is some kind of rule of thumb I am not aware of in android?

Answer (score 0):

All good now, after hours of searching on the internet and looking at the code, the culprit was simply making the progress bar and the text view static. I originally had them only as private. This solved my whole issue. Hopefully if anyone else runs into this issue they can see this solution.